# Calculate post dominator with non exiting control flow

Tags: graphs, compilers, static-analysis

Using the basic algorithm to calculate post dominators I run into trouble when working with a CFG containing an infinite loop (i.e., not terminating).

The algorithm:

```
// post dominator of the start node is the start itself
 PDom(n0) = {n0}
 // for all other nodes, set all nodes as the post dominators
 for each n in N - {n0}
     Dom(n) = N;
 // iteratively eliminate nodes that are not post dominators
 while changes in any PDom(n)
     for each n in N - {n0}:
         PDom(n) = {n} union with intersection over PDom(p) for all p in post(n)
```

I have the following function:

```
function x: 
  while true:
     doNothing
```

Which has the following CFG graph:

```
                              -CFG->
[METHOD_START] -CFG-> [WHILE]        [DO_NOTHING]  [METHOD_END]
                              <-CFG-
```

When calculating the post dominator tree (starting from `METHOD_END`) this runs in the obvious problem, that there is no elimination of any nodes in `PDom`

The start and final `PDom` will be:

```
METHOD_RETURN : { METHOD_RETURN }
METHOD_START  : { METHOD_RETURN, DO_NOTHING, WHILE, METHOD_START }
WHILE         : { METHOD_RETURN, DO_NOTHING, WHILE, METHOD_START }
DO_NOTHING    : { METHOD_RETURN, DO_NOTHING, WHILE, METHOD_START }
```

This would imply, that `WHILE` is post dominated by `METHOD_START` which is obviously false.

**How do I have to account for infinite loops in post dominator calculations?**

Using the definition of (post) domination of "a node d (post) dominates a node n if every path from the start node to n must go through d" I would assume that the domination tree would have to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was trying to apply the domination algorithm on a forest, i.e., the method has multiple different graphs. However, the algorithm is only defined on a graph. Consequently, before applying the algorithm to the method graph I need to calculate the CFG slice from the start point. I..e, in the given example this would be only `{ METHOD_RETURN }`.